# Offline application in sencha touch 2 not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to to build an offline application in sencha touch 2 using mvc structure. In offline mode page displayed is blank. I checked developer tool and there was an error as

"Failed to load resource     http://ipaddress/AppName/app/view/LoginViewport.js?_dc=1334316337812 "

We can also see in the above error, there is some data appended to "LoginViewPort.js", and that might be the problem.
Please help.

Comment: Don't worry about the `GET` parameter (`_dc=1334316337812`) that's appended to your URL. Sencha Touch 2 does it while in development mode so that file caching doesn't work and every page load forces the browser to download a new copy. I am curious to know if you are doing anything special for offline mode development (apart from putting your web browser in the offline mode).

Comment: I have a one other doubt, is it compulsory to have only one html page(i.e index.htm) and app.js(which has Ext.application).  I am storing data locally and if server connection is available, it looks for data updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works ones we go for production. Because  all the mvc structure files will be copied into one file.

Answer (score 0):

When I get that error, it means I didn't place the file in the correct location Sencha Touch is expecting.  It is perhaps you made the directory VIEWS and it is looking in VIEW for the information?  Did you define it like so?

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    views: ['LoginViewport'],
...

    Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginViewport', {
...
```

I believe this would mean it would look in the view folder for the file LoginViewport.js.

Comment: LoginViewport is in view directory and the definition is as you shown. But still I have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even though sencha can find the file in the view folder. It ignores it for some reason. If you rename the folder to views it should work. At least that's what it did in my project.